# Classify text as logical/ not logical

Tags: nlp, text-mining, text-classification

Can some one advise me direction where to look in.Or some resources. Here is a task:

1. User leaves feed back-text with min 50 characters.
2. I need to check if it's normal human sentences/ word combination OR just bag of words and characters.

For ex ( 1-normal, 0-not normal):

"I wrote question.hope for answer" - 1(class)

"Bla bla goog goog goog gooo" - 0(class)

Maybe some dataset available.or some approach?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is simply a [language model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model). This is a very common task so you should be able to find code and data easily. [This question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/38540/64377) gives some pointers for Python (be careful, the accepted answer is incorrect according to the two other answers).

Applying the language model to a sentence gives you a probability (or a perplexity score,  which works the opposite way), so you have to define a threshold in order to classify as real language or not.

Comment: Let me clarify bit: my task is simple classification task, where I use LM and dataset with (readable/not readable) samples? Same as if I would wanted to classify for Pos/Neg sentiment? In such case I can use fast.ai or bert+keras.

Comment: Yes but if you want to properly check if the text is readable you need to use a model which uses the words as features, that's what a language model does. The easiest way is probably to use a pre-trained model as described in the linked question. If you want an even simpler option you can just check whether the words appear in a dictionary, but that's quite limited.

Comment: Or I can use gpt as the last comment in question you sent me @Erwan.                             
tokenizer = OpenAIGPTTokenizer.from_pretrained('openai-gpt')